# How Web Api application start event get fired?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have made a REST web api and I thought the application_start() event of a web api should triggered once you start the web service from IIS manager, however, what I have observed to my web api is it only triggered by the first web request which reached to the web service. I was wondering if this is supposed to be or I did it incorrectly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it is. From the docs:

> Called when the first resource (such as a page) in an ASP.NET
>   application is requested. The Application_Startmethod is called only
>   one time during the life cycle of an application. You can use this
>   method to perform startup tasks such as loading data into the cache
>   and initializing static values.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx

Comment: Thanks Robert, what happened if I want to add a timer to trigger some function inside the web api? Do I have to make an outside web request to actually trigger this function as well? Or the timer event can internally fire the function?

Comment: I would not hijack that event in a timer. I would use something like http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Comment: I'd ask another question on the subject